# Detect the event ActiveWorkbook.Save from personal.xlsm in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have all macros stored in personal.xlsm and untill now I have used a standard filter to hide/show columns. The new feature I want to implement now is that each user can have their own filter if they would like to. So basically i look in a folder for a personal filter if it exist and if it does it use that filter instead of the standard one.

But my problem is that i want to load a personal filter on `workbookOpen` event and reset to standard filter on the `beforeClose` event. My question is if I can do this from personal.xlsm in a way? Or do I have to manually go through all 250 workbooks and add in thisworkbook module `onOpen` and `beforeClose`  events to call my method createFilter and resetFilter?

Here is a link to [personal.xlsm](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566) for those who are not familiar with that methodology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In personal.xlsm, create a class module named "Helper". Place the following code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents xlApp As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set xlApp = Application

End Sub

Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

    'Your code here

End Sub
```

Your code for loading a filter should go in the 'Your code here bit.

Add a standard code module and add this code:

```
Public MyHelper As Helper
```

Finally, in the Workbook_Open event of personal.xlsm, place this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set MyHelper = New Helper

End Sub
```

Save personal.xlsm and restart Excel.

Comment: Thanks, however it works only when you open the first instance of excel and not when I open more workbooks. Lets say I have a.xlsx open and then open a new workbook b.xlsx the 'Private Sub Workbook_open()
method will not be triggered in personal.xlsb because is already open and hence logically also new helper will not be exceuted. Am i missing something?

Comment: Was some problem earlier with resetting of the object during the session. Works superb now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in helper if someones needs it:

```
Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Dim myPath As String
    On error resume next
    If InStr(UCase(ActiveWorkbook.Name), "PARTSLIST") And (InStr(UCase(ActiveWorkbook.Name), "FILTERPARTSLIST") = 0) Then
        myPath = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1)
        If Dir(myPath & "\filterPartsList.xlsx") <> "" Then  '
            Call ColumnCreater.updateFilter
        Else
            Call ColumnCreater.filterCreationStandard
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```